# Iter through defaultdict of defaultdict on Python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6, defaultdict

In order to have the number of failed first requests of different urls from an access log with Python, I had to create a defaultdict of defaultdict in this way:

```
apache_status_dict = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
```

I count the number of failed requests using an apachelog parser:

```
for index, line in enumerate(open(path+aFile)):    
   if int(str(data['%>s'])[0]) == 4 or int(str(data['%>s'])[0]) == 5:
        apache_status_dict[data['%{Referer}i']][data['%r']] += 1
```

The server I'm working on have Python 2.6 installed and there is no way to update it. So is there any way to make something like this in my code :

```
for url in apache_status_dict:
  for req in url:
     <code...>
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for url in apache_status_dict.keys():
  for req in apache_status_dict[url]:
      print apache_status_dict[url][req]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always iterate through `defaultdict` items:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for i in d.items():
   # do something
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I iterate through each item of d.items() ?

Comment: if you have for example dict like `[('url://foo.com', [err, err, ok]), ('url://bar.org', [ok, ok, ok])]`, then you should just unpack like `for url, status in d.items()`:

Comment: In fact, I wanted to have the total number of failed requests per request and url. Thank you for your answer PYPL's answer was exactly what I was looking for